# MATLAB Linear Congruential Generator (LCG) for Random Numbers and 64-bit unsigned int multiplication

Tags: c, matlab, random, 64-bit

I would like to implement a 64-bit [`L'Ecuyer LCG`](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1999-68-225/S0025-5718-99-00996-5/S0025-5718-99-00996-5.pdf) on MATLAB, since I wrote it on C, to replicate some results.

The pure Mutiplicative LCG (MLCG) is easily obtained by `X_{n+1} = a * X_{n} mod m`, where `a` and `m` are the two constant taken from the table of L'Ecuyer's article. In my case I used

```
a = 1181783497276652981
m = 2^64
```

As pointed out e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63731432/how-to-implement-the-modulus-264-in-c-for-linear-congruential-generator-lcg) in C there are no problem in doing multiplication of 64-bits `a` and `X_{n}` is automagically truncated to the remainder of division by `2^64` (for `uint64_t`, so that I only need to do

```
rnd = A_ecu1b64 * rnd;
```

to obtain the successive random number. In MATLAB, sadly, this is not like so, instead when `a * X_{n}` is bigger than `m` is gets truncated to `2^64` and then the successive remainders are always 0.

How can I implement the same MLCG on MATLAB?

Comment: The modular arithmetic of C's `uint64_t` works only if _m_ = 2⁶⁴, not if _m_ = 2⁶⁴ − 1. The linked PDF and the linked answer say so, but your question has it wrong. Anyway, you can handle this by writing your own modulo multiplication [like so](https://ideone.com/Yw8n4y) by splitting the 64-bit ints into two 32-bit hi and lo parts. (But perhaps there is a better way to do this in Matlab.)

Comment: Thanks for the code, my teachers always used `m = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFULL` without much bothering, but yes in the linked table is written _m_ = 2⁶⁴, I always took for granded that it wouldn't have changed much. I think this is because in my program `m` is never used for modulo operation, but truncation internally occurs in `A_ecu1b64 * rnd`. I need to correct the question.

Comment: Rather `m = m = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFULL` was used as inverse to get floating point random numbers as `#define mInv 1./m` so that `r = (double) rnd * mInv;` was effectively in `[0, 1]`.

Comment: Implementing LCG would require some general precision math package, or doing math with strings. This is because more or less everything is a double, see for details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34591588/uint64-is-not-exact-for-vectors-in-matlab)

Comment: @MOehm: But m *is* 2⁶⁴, not 2⁶⁴ − 1.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk: Yes, but an earlier version of the question had 2⁶⁴ − 1. The OP asks how to replicate C's wrapping on overflowing 64-bit unsigned int arithmetic, which effectively is modulo 2⁶⁴.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux: If I read that answer correctly, the double-resolution issue arisies only with number _literals_ and the `uint64(123...)` syntax seems to solve that. I guess that doing arithmetic with `uint64`'s works -- otherwise, why have an `uint64` type at all?

Comment: @opisthofulax: A double cannot represent 2⁶⁴ − 1; `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFULL` in double is represented as 2⁶⁴ or `0x1p+64` in hex exponential. On the other hand, 2⁶⁴ cannot be represented with a `uin64`, because it wraps and has a value of zero, so normalizing with a factor of 1 / (2⁶⁴ − 1) is just a workaround to get an actual factor of 2⁻⁶⁴.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that explains a lot. Then the workaround on C is quite nice, I just don't get how a similar truncation cannot be done in MATLAB, seems quite natural to me, but probably was removed not to create confusion in debugging arising meaningless results when going above 2⁶⁴.

Comment: try to multiply large uint64() numbers and just check the result.

Comment: @Severin Pappadeux in MATLAB after an `uint64` reaches `18446744073709551615` further mutiplications give again `18446744073709551615`.

Comment: Well, did you try to print it as binary and count bits?

Comment: Anyway, there is no truncation like in C, no free modulo operation - and for uint64 it means you have to have 64x64-> 128 multiplication and them mod(result, 2^64) operation.

Comment: Nothing changes in binary i suppose, `18446744073709551615` will be still in binary `1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111`.

Comment: @Severin Pappadeux MATLAB do not have a type for 128-bit integers, so if you have some hints on how to perform _"64x64-> 128 multiplication and then mod(result, 2^64) operation"_ you are welcome.

Comment: @opisthofulax: In the C code I posted yesterday, the function `clamp_mul` implements Matlab's multiplication behaviour. You should be able to rewrite the `mod_mil` function for Matlab and use it in your LCG. (But you can just write `a * b` instead of `clamp_mul(a, b)`, I guess.)

Comment: Well, vpi might work, https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22725-variable-precision-integer-arithmetic.  But it would be SLOW vs uint64

Comment: I'll try implementing `mod_mil` from @M Oehm, thanks for now.

Comment: Well, 64x64 gives you 64bits with UINT64_MAX in the case of overflow.